# How To Use Flux Stores

Tags: single-page-application, reactjs-flux

Most examples of Flux use a todo or chat example.  In all those examples, the data set you are storing is somewhat small and and be kept locally so not exactly sure if my planned use of stores falls in line with the flux "way".

The way I intend to use stores are somewhat like ORM repositories.  A way to access data in multiple ways and persist data to the data service, whatever that might be.

Lets say I am building a project management system.  I would probably have methods like these for data retrieval:

- getIssueById
- getIssuesByProject
- getIssuesByAssignedUser
- getIssueComments
- getIssueCommentById
- etc...

I would also have methods like this for persisting data to the data service:

- addIssue
- updateIssue
- removeIssue
- addIssueComment
- etc...

The one main thing I would not do is locally store any issue data (and for that matter most store data that related to a data store).  Most of the data is important to have fresh because maybe the issue status has updated since I last retrieved that issue.  All my data retrieval method would probably always make an API requests to the the latest data.

Is this against the flux "way"?  Are there any issue with going about flux in this way?

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't get too hung up on the term "store". You need create application state in some way if you want your components to render something. If you need to clear that state every time a different request is made, no problem. Here's how things would flow with getIssueById(), as an example:

1. component calls store.getIssueById(id)
2. returns empty object since issue isn't in store's cache
3. the store calls action.fetchIssue(id)
4. component renders empty state
5. server responds with issue data and calls action.receiveIssue(data)
6. store caches that data and dispatches a change event
7. component responds to event by calling store.getIssueById(id)
8. the issue data is returned
9. component renders data

Persisting changes would be similar, with only the most recent server response being held in the store.

1. user interaction in component triggers action.updateIssue(modifiedIssue)
2. store handles action, sending changes to server
3. server responds with updated issue and calls action.receiveIssue(data)

...and so on with the last 4 steps from above.

As you can see, it's not really about modeling your data, just controlling how it comes and goes.